# Pagina fica travado no primeiro carregamento. Apos atualizar (refresh) funciona normal. Se limpa cache, volta a travar

Tags: javascript, html5

esse problema esta me atazanando por uns dias ja.. Pesquisei e fiz varias verificações e alteracoes e nao  consigo achar o problema.

A pagina fica travada no carregamento por alguma razão.

- se voce ir no 'inspecionador' verá que a pagina está toda carregada em html, porém nao renderiza e fica um 'BRANCO', apesar aparecer os links quando passa o mouse em cima;
- apos o refresh, a pagina carrega e funciona normalmente.. e segue funcionando até q se limpe o cache, aí ela trava denovo;
- o estranho é q nao dá nenhum erro no console nem nada;
- esse problema da em varios browsers e em outros computadores em locais diferentes;

vejam por vcs mesmos:

ps: a menos q mude o useragent nao dá pra testar acessando com mobile, porque voce vai ser redirecionado para o mobile site, onde ja nao tem mais esse errto

http://romapy.com/index.php

obrigado

Answer (score 1):

> Sua página só carregou depois que cliquei em "parar de carregar" do browser e depois em "Refresh"

Realmente era questao de organização dos scripts em relação a outros e a biblioteca jquery, com um arquivo php no meio.

Eu utilizava um arquivo php para incluir varios scripts, e por alguma razao que eu nao identifiquei direito, alguns desses scripts, incluindo uma bibliotecha jquery era carregado no cache na primeira vez q era carregado, e o carregamento do site travava ao baixar esta biblioteca. Sendo assim, a segunda vez em diante q o site era acessado funcionava normal e até carregava mais rapido, pois os arquivos necessarios ja estavam no cache. Ao limparo cache dava o mesmo problema.

O problema foi dificil de identificar pq nao dava nenhum erro. O CLONE do @Leo Caraciiolo ajudou bastante, pois no clone nao dava problema e pude perceber que era algo que acontecia quando eu baixava esses scripts incluidos atraves do arquivo php, pois no clone, os scripts ja eram incluido no codigo.

Bom, sendo assim, tirei todos scripts do arquivo php, e reorganizei meus scripts seguindo este documento:

> https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Conclusão: 
1. Já usei varias vezes arquivos php para gerar scripts dinamicos, mas ao menos q essa tecnica seja indispensável, não é uma boa pratica usa-la. Alem de deixar mais lento o carregamento pode dar problemas de bloqueio de pagina.

2. Organização dos scripts é importantissima e diretamente ligado com a performance da pagina. Atenção redobrada a isto.